# Change button title when clicking it

Tags: ios, swift

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var words: UILabel!

    var positiveWords = ["dont give up","keep going","you can do that","your are strong"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    @IBAction func wordsButton(_ sender: Any) {

        for w in positiveWords {

         // show array in label
            words.text = "\(w)" 

        }

    }
}
```

When I click the button it shows only one word but I want to show another word while clicking, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. But here is different ways to solve your problem

```
//Wil generate different word every time you press the button
   func wordsButton(_ sender: Any) { 
        words.text = positiveWords.randomElement(
   }
```

if you want to add the whole array at once

```
  func wordsButton(_ sender: Any) { 
     for w in positiveWords {
            words.text! += "\(w) "
        } 
  }
```

if you want to add one at a time

```
var displayedWords = o
  func wordsButton(_ sender: Any) { 
     var totalWords = positiveWords.count
        if displayedWords < totalWords {
            label.text! += "\(positiveWords[displayedWords]) "
            displayedWords += 1
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a word which is displayed to a user is the last one of the positiveWords array of a Strings because you use a control flow [For-In Loop](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) which enumerate the array and set a current element to a label.

**Solution:**

Standard Library Array function `joined(separator:)`

```
@IBAction
func wordsButton(_ sender: Any) {

    words.text = positiveWords.joined(separator: ", ")

}
```

For-In Loop

```
func wordsButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var labelWord: String = ""
    for word in positiveWords {
        labelWord = labelWord + ", " + word
    }
    words.text = labelWord
}
```